# difference between ftrace function statistics and oprofile

Tags: linux, profiling, oprofile, ftrace

May anyone please compare `ftrace` statistics and `oprofile`?
We observed the following phenomenons:

- with `oprofile` enabled during the network performance test, we see little impact to the performance test (compare to the case where `oprofile` is not enabled)
  with ftrace profiler (`CONFIG_FUNCTION_PROFILER`),
- when we enabled the profiler, the performance of the network test degrade about 90%.
- There are many functions that were sampled less in `oprofile` report, but in the report of ftrace profile, they take a lot of time to execute (most of them are `skb_alloc` and `skb_free`).

If you use both of these profiling before, please give your suggestion about their accuracies?